# Update member in mongoose

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, passport.js

I am using passport.js and I'd like to update the profile for the currently logged in Member and save it to the database. Right now I am using save but I am worried that this could lead to issues when someone else modifies this profile at the same time. Instead I would like to use MongoDB's upsert feature.

```
function updateProfile(req, res) {
    var user = req.user
    var form = req.body
    var profile = {
        name: form.profileRealName,
        bio: form.profileBio,
        url: form.profileUrl,
        location: form.profileLocation
    }

    user.profile = profile
    logger.info(user)

    user.save(function(err) {
        if(err)
            next(err)
        else
            res.redirect(302, '/settings/profile')
    })  
}
```

Actually that didn't throw errors but the document in the database hasn't been changed.

**My question:**

What's the best way to upsert my logged in user?

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the _id of the user and use that to look for it in the database to update the specified document.

```
function updateProfile(req, res) {
  var options = {
                  upsert : true,
                  new    : true
                 }
  var    user  = req.body._id
  var    form  = req.body

  db.User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: user}, form, options, (err, user) => {
    if(err) {
      res.json(err)
    }else{
      res.json(user)
      console.log('details: %s', user);
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I have rewritten it a bit and now it throws "user" is not defined for the callback parameters `(err, user)`. That's my code: http://i.imgur.com/fJeU6Ur.png

Comment: @kentor Looks like it is undefined because it does not find a user in your query, or that userId is undefined. Try setting userid to `var userId = req.body._id` you should be passing the the id value in the body. Or if you are passing the id in the params it would be `var userid = req.params.id`